# PowerBI data model conversion

Tags: powerpivot, powerbi

I published my Power BI dashboard to the cloud using Import Excel Workbook Content. Unfortunately my hard disk dies and I lost the original workbook (which contains PowerPivot data model).

Can I convert PBIX file to PowerPivot model? I actually tried to rename the file to .zip and I could see a file called DataModel which has the similar file size as my original model but I don't know what to do with it.

Help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the conversion between a Power Pivot for Excel data model and a Power BI data model is one way from Power Pivot for Excel to Power BI.

May I ask why you need to convert back to Power Pivot? Power BI Desktop offers Power Pivot, so you can do your data modelling and measure definition there.

I've seen some people talk about changing the file extension to '.zip', opening up the archive, removing the DATA file, putting that DATA file into a similarly renamed and unzipped Excel document in the 'model' folder, and then rezipping and renaming the Excel file back to '.xlsx'. I've never had luck with this.

Comment: My original model was in powerpivot and I basically want to revert back to the stage before PowerBI it. Guess I need to re-do my model based on my memory :(

Comment: You don't have to rebuild based on memory. The model exists in the .pbix, with all of the measures an relationships defined. At worst you have to copy-paste. My question is why do you need to do your model authoring in Power Pivot for Excel? Why can you not do your model authoring the the Power Pivot portion of Power BI Desktop?

Comment: I think my original question was misleading actually. I looked again, I actually don't have pbix file at all. I had it and published it to my app.powerbi account then the next day my hard disk blew up, both model and pbix are in C:\ so I guess my requirement is really how can I get the pbix file out of what already published in my account? Is this possible?

Comment: I am very confused now. Do you or do you not have a .pbix file accessible to you on a functioning local drive?   --- OR --- Is the only extant copy of your data living on the Power BI Service at app.powerbi.com, meaning no .pbix file exists on any drive you have access to?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself properly - the only copy I have now is on Power BI server at app.powerbi and I don't have pbix file or model with me. Guess its only memory re-build work now you think?

Comment: Yes, you are unfortunately out of luck if that is the situation. Exporting a .pbix from Power BI is a feature that is currently "Under Review" by the developers. You can vote for it at this link: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/suggestions/6856196-export-power-bi-report-in-a-pbix-file  And, I truly don't want to sound smug here, but you should really consider backing up important work.

Comment: Oh yeah I do that regularly just over the holiday internet was slow so I worked offline and intended to upload it when next in office. Out of luck I guess. Thanks for replies tho.